# shutil copy files but deletes data

Tags: python, scrapy, shutil

The following code works sometimes, it pushes it to the directory it needs to be in and IT always copy the file, however sometimes there is no data in the csv files in the leadparser directory.

```
import csv
import re
import os
import shutil


class myExporter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.filename = 'output%s.csv'
        self.srcfile = '/Users/poweruser/Applications/pythonwork/bbbscrap2/scrape/' + self.filename
        while os.path.exists(self.srcfile % self.i):
            self.i += 1
        self.folderdes = '/Users/poweruser/Applications/pythonwork/leadparser/newfiles'
        self.myCSV = csv.writer(open(self.filename % self.i,  'w'))
        self.myCSV.writerow(['Email', 'Website', 'Phone Number', 'Location'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.myCSV.writerow([item['email'],
                             item['website'],
                             item['phonenumber'],
                             item['location']])
        self.folderPath = os.path.join(
            self.folderdes, os.path.basename(self.srcfile % self.i))
        shutil.copy(self.srcfile % self.i, self.folderPath)

        return item
```

Comment: Data is written not at once, only when file is closed. Where do you close the file?

Comment: i didn't close the file

Comment: how would i close this ?

Comment: yeah this construct `csv.writer(open(self.filename % self.i,  'w'))` doesn't allow control on file closure. So you're writing in a file which isn't closed or flushed. Plus you don't have the handle. Why would you copy the file at each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the file, to get all data written:

```
import csv
import re
import os
import shutil

SRCFILE = '/Users/poweruser/Applications/pythonwork/bbbscrap2/scrape/output%s.csv'
DESTINATION_FOLDER = '/Users/poweruser/Applications/pythonwork/leadparser/newfiles'

class myExporter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        i = 0
        while os.path.exists(SRCFILE % i):
            i += 1
        self.filename = SRCFILE % i
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as output:
            output = csv.writer(output)
            output.writerow(['Email', 'Website', 'Phone Number', 'Location'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        with open(self.filename, 'a') as output:
            output = csv.writer(output)
            output.writerow([item['email'],
                             item['website'],
                             item['phonenumber'],
                             item['location']])
        folder = os.path.join(DESTINATION_FOLDER, os.path.basename(self.filename))
        shutil.copy(self.filename, folder)
        return item
```